# Legend only to display what is shown in Print Composer QGIS 1.8.4

Tags: qgis, printing

I am using the 625k bedrock data from BGS. I have a range of site across scotland.  I have then clipped the file down to within a 70Km radius of each site, a lot of over lapping areas with disintegrated boundaries ends up with most of scotland covered.

However, i have categorised the style of the bedrock data by name.

When i place the legend in there seems to be an awful amount of classes.

Bar going through each layer and ascertaining if it is displayed or not is there a way to display only the parts of the layer you can see in the legend.

Cannot show images due to client confidentiality.